# Android Studio" Edit the string resource value from the layout.xml without switching to strings.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

We can extract the string resources from the directly hard coded string into **`string.xml`** resource file? But how can we edit the string resource value?

**For Example:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/notes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/notes 
/>
```

How do I change the value of `@string/notes` right from the layout file?

Answer (score 4):

I just open wherever the variable is stored:

**Windows:**
Highlight the variable and press **CTRL + B** or **CTRL + Click**

**Mac:**
Same thing as Windows only CMD instead of CTRL